# A phrase meaning that something became not so important compared to something else

Tags: idioms

I'm working on the translation of the article from Polish to English. It literally says "The discussion on the origin of the languages **pales**/**blanches** compared to the basic debate the linguists are holding nowadays"

The word is used  in its idiomatic meaning: to lose importance, become unimportant/unrelevant, and I would like to find the English equivalent.

Comment: It'd be mightily appreciated if words were written in its entirety, like *'something'* :)

Comment: You could say [A plays second fiddle to B](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/play-second-fiddle) in some contexts.

Comment: "*Don't sweat the small stuff.*"

Answer (score 2):

"**Pales in comparison to**" works just fine in English (and [is much more commonly phrased that particular way](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pales%20in%20comparison%20to%2Cpales%20compared%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpales%20in%20comparison%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpales%20compared%20to%3B%2Cc0) instead of "pales compared to").

Also, *dibate* should probably be *debate* in your translation.

Please also feel free to check out our sister site, [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), "for speakers of other languages learning English."

Comment: thanx a lot! yeah, "debate" was automatic

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pales+into+insignificance%2Cpales+in+comparison%2Cpales+when+compared&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpales%20into%20insignificance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpales%20in%20comparison%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpales%20when%20compared%3B%2Cc0) show that 'pales in comparison ...' has indeed been favoured over 'pales into insignificance' since about 1984. But the latter is still in fairly common use. (References should be attributed.)

Comment: @BeataZ if this answered your question, feel free to mark it as Accepted Answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to Stack Exchange!